GCSE maths level - Is it normal for there to be two possibilities of factorisation for quadratics with a coefficient of x?
The problem and my working
It would be useful to know, and its impossible to find anywhere easily on the internet. There also definitely could be a hole in my reasoning too.
It was for factorising a fraction to try and simplify, and if there where two different factorisations then it would make it quite annoying during an exam.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

(2x-12)(x-5)=2(x-6)(x-5)=(x-6)(2x-10) They're all the same.

To avoid confusion, factor out the coefficient at $x^2$ first, i.e. $2(x^2-11x+30)$ then factor the quadratic in parenthesis.

Factorizations are unique up to constant factors, and you don't need something as elaborate as your example to see why "up to constant factors" needs to be included. Note that $x^2$ can be factored in infinitely many different ways: $x \cdot x = (2x) \cdot (\frac{1}{2}x) = (10x) \cdot (0.1x)$ etc. And if the use of fractions is a concern, then note there are several ways to factor $120x^2.$

@Gwen This is exactly what i was missing out on. Thanks!

Note that the two attempts you made are equivalent. $-10x-12x$ is the same thing as $12x-10x$, just the terms are in different orders. Neither is " more correct" than the other as both lead you to the same solutions.
$$(2x-12)(x-5)=0$$
$$x+6=0,  x=5$$
$$x=6,x=5$$
Compare to the other factorization you did:
$$(2x-10)(x-6)=0$$
$$x+5=0,  x=6$$
$$x=5, x=6$$
They both give the solution $x=5$ and $x=6$. Your teacher should give credit for both factorizations.

Hi there!
Thanks for the speedy reply, but as stated (vaguely) in the previous post, it was a factorise and simplify the fraction question, where on the top was (x+6) and (x-6), meaning that an equivalent factorisation must be made for the bottom. However, it is useful to know that, depending on the order you decide to factorise, the outcome will be different.
I guess in the exam I may have to try both orders.

You seem to get mixed up, there is only one factorization, except for a konstant factor, The easies way is find the two solutions x1,x2 of p(x)=0 than you have  const*(x-x1)*(x-x2)
